# RadTreeNode re order based on userlogin then sort alphabetically

Tags: c#, asp.net, radtreeview

Please let me know if i can achieve based on the following scenario

So, if the user login as domain/dan.campbell then i need to sort the RadTreeView as in the following:

CAMPBELL, DAN

- Nike
- Puma

ANSTON, ERIC

- Addidas
- Puma

BRIAN, ERIC

- Addidas
- Puma

Based on the following code, the current tree is showing as in the following:

ANSTON, ERIC

- Addidas
- Puma

BRIAN, ERIC

- Addidas
- Puma

CAMPBELL, DAN

- Nike
- Puma

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              BuildTree();
              SortClass();
          }

  ```
      //Sort all RadTreeNode in Ascending
      public void SortClass()
      {
          SortNodes(treProduct.Nodes);
      }
  ```

  public void BuildTree()
  {
      EntityCollection collection = GetProduct();
      treProduct.Nodes.Clear();

  ```
      ArrayList pgnodes = new ArrayList();
      RadTreeNode pnode = null;
      RadTreeNode snode = null;

      foreach (ProductEntity p in collection)
      {
          pnode = null;
          foreach(RadTreeNode n in pgnodes)
          {
             if(n.Text.Trim() == p.LastName.Trim().ToUpper() + "," +" " + p.FirstName.Trim().ToUpper())
             {
                pnode = n;
                break;
             }   
          } 

          if(pnode != null)
          {
              RadTreeNode productNode = new RadTreeNode(p.ProductName.toString());  
              pnode.nodes.Add(productNode);  
          }
          else
          {
             RadTreeNode userNode = new RadTreeNode(p.LastName.Trim().ToUpper() + "," +" " + p.FirstName.Trim().ToUpper());

             RadTreeNode productNode = new RadTreeNode(p.ProductName.toString()); 
             userNode.Nodes.Add(productNode);
             pgnodes.Add(userNode);   
          }
      }

      foreach(RadTreeNode pg in pgnodes)
      {
          treProduct.Nodes.Add(pg);
      }
      treProduct.CollapseAllNode();

  }




   /// <summary>
      /// The sort node is called for each node level sorting the child node
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="collection"></param>

  public void Sort(RadTreeNodeCollection collection)
  {
          RadTreeNode[] nodes = new RadTreeNode[collection.Count];
          collection.CopyTo(nodes, 0);
          Array.Sort(nodes, new NodeSorter());
          collection.Clear();
          collection.AddRange(nodes);
  }
      /// <summary>
      /// SortNodes is a recursive method enumarating and sorting all area
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="collection"></param>

  private void SortNodes(RadTreeNodeCollection collection)
  {
          Sort(collection);

          foreach (RadTreeNode node in collection)
          {
              if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
              {
                  SortNodes(node.Nodes);
              }

          }
   }
      /// <summary>
      /// TreeNodeCOmpare define the sorting criteria
      /// </summary>
   public class NodeSorter : IComparer
   {
          public int Compare(object x, object y)
          {
              RadTreeNode tx = (RadTreeNode)x;
              RadTreeNode ty = (RadTreeNode)y;

              //if (tx.Text.Length != ty.Text.Length)

              //    return tx.Text.Length - ty.Text.Length;
              return string.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text);


          }

    }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public String FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            string firstName = null;
            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Substring(1);
            string[] loginNameParts = userName.Split('\\');
            string loginNameWithoutDomain = loginNameParts[1];


            var names = loginNameWithoutDomain.Split('.');


            firstName = names[0];

            return firstName;

        }
    }
    public String LastName
    {
        get
        {
            string lastName = null;
            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Substring(1);
            string[] loginNameParts = userName.Split('\\');
            string loginNameWithoutDomain = loginNameParts[1];


            var names = loginNameWithoutDomain.Split('.');

            lastName = names[1];


            return lastName;

        }
    }
    public void SortClass()
    {
        SortNodes(treProduct.Nodes);

        string nameToFind = LastName.Trim().ToUpper() + "," + " " + FirstName.Trim().ToUpper();
        var node = treProduct.FindNodeByText(nameToFind);
        if (node != null)
        {
            node.Remove();
            treProduct.Nodes.Insert(0, node);
            treProduct.Nodes[0].Expanded = true;
            treProduct.Nodes[0].ExpandChildNodes();
        }
    }

  public void Sort(RadTreeNodeCollection collection)
    {
        RadTreeNode[] nodes = new RadTreeNode[collection.Count];
        collection.CopyTo(nodes, 0);
        Array.Sort(nodes, new NodeSorter());
        collection.Clear();
        collection.AddRange(nodes);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// SortNodes is a recursive method enumarating and sorting all area
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection"></param>

    private void SortNodes(RadTreeNodeCollection collection)
    {
        Sort(collection);

        foreach (RadTreeNode node in collection)
        {
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                SortNodes(node.Nodes);
            }

        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// TreeNodeCOmpare define the sorting criteria
    /// </summary>
    public class NodeSorter : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            RadTreeNode tx = (RadTreeNode)x;
            RadTreeNode ty = (RadTreeNode)y;

            //if (tx.Text.Length != ty.Text.Length)

            //    return tx.Text.Length - ty.Text.Length;
            return string.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text);


        }

    }
```